# Error opening installation log file. Verify that the specified location exists and is writable

Tags: windows, logging, installation

### Problem

Attempting to install an application in Windows produces the following message:

> Error opening installation log file. Verify that the specified location exists and is writable.

### Solution

When you try to install application, a temp folder will be created, e.g.
`Administrator\AppData\Local\{F2234F94-BDEB-4DBD-9ACB-D3AB5C8526C5}
{F2234F94-BDEB-4DBD-9ACB-D3AB5C8526C5}`.  Go to this directory and double-click the `.MSI` file and installation will restart and succeed.

Answer (score 17):

This is a super easy solution:

> Task Manager to kill explorer.exe, and then start a new instance of it.

Source: https://support.software.dell.com/kb/134431

Comment: The solution you linked appears to be behind a login, any way you could pull some of the pertinent details out so we can all benefit?

Comment: You can see this Microsoft article. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2564571/error-opening-installation-log-file-verify-that-the-specified-location for more information, which mentions uninstallation, but also applies to installation and worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

1. Hit CTRL-ALT-DEL to launch Task Manager or right-click Desktop Task
   Bar and choose Start Task Manager.
2. Click Processes Tab.
3. Locate and select the explorer.exe, click End Process.
4. You may need to select Show Processes from all users.

[image: Task manager]

- Click End Process to the prompt.
- Your Desktop Icons and Desktop Bar will disappear.
- Hit CTRL-ALT-DEL to launch Task Manager again.
- Click File -> New Task (Run...).
- Type explorer.exe and click Ok.
- Your Desktop Task bar and Icons should appear again.

[image: New task]

Comment: On a terminal server, you need to kill explorer for all users. For me it was easier to restart than to kill all explorer processes and then explain to the users to use Run to start explorer.

Answer (score 3):

You can encounter this error if TMP and TEMP directories are different. This can result in installer files being written to TMP but when attempting to read those files using the TEMP value you see in the error.

Confirm that both values are referring to the same path. For example, from a command prompt:

```
 set TEMP=%tmp%
```

and then run the installation again

Otherwise, it looks like an operating system permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the procedure with stopping and starting explorer.exe fails, you can try:

In Command Prompt type

```
echo %temp%
```

Go to the folder in the output and check whether it is accessible. In case it is a file, remove it.